# Email sending using gmail works fine but domain mail server throws error?

Tags: c#, windows

Gmail works fine but domain mail server throws below error.

The server response was 5.7.1. Receipient address rejected : Access denied

```
     try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            message.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text.Trim());
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox5.Text.Trim()));
            message.Subject = "Test";
            message.Body ="Test Message";

            smtp.Port = int.Parse(textBox4.Text.Trim());
            smtp.Host = textBox3.Text.Trim();
            smtp.EnableSsl = checkBox1.Checked;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = checkBox2.Checked;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text.Trim(), textBox2.Text.Trim());
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(message);
            MessageBox.Show("Message sent");
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            //chTextBox1.Text = "";
        }
```

i tried enable both ssl and netrk crediential also. same error as above

Comment: it is not only the problem of credentials, it also soemtimes that particulr IP needs to be accessible. For example if you have separate SMTP server then that needs to be accessible from your machine. otherwise this will happen.

Comment: @RajeshB now what i have to do?

Comment: are you using your own SMTP server or any free like Gmail or any other?

Comment: @RajeshB own i think

Comment: Then check whether you are able to do telnet for that IP address from your server machine. To activate telnet you need to do these steps.

You have to go to Control Panel>Programs>Turn Windows features on or off. Then, check "Telnet Client" and save the changes. You might have to wait about a few minutes before the change could take effect.

once Telnet installed then open command prompt and command like "Telnet ip port" without quotes. Telnet is the command name, IP is the SMTP one, And portnumber is Port of that SMTP. Once if you run you can see black window which means its connected.

Comment: Example: Telnet 10.101.10.10 457 - if output is black window then you have access else you dont have access. If you have access but mail is not working you needs to check on Firewall inbound and outbound rules for that server to access SMTP. Just google it you will get idea

Comment: @RajeshB tq so much

Comment: did you try that out? I hope this is related to firewall only.